# ReactJS: How-to set focus to input-element when it enters the DOM?

Tags: reactjs

How to set focus to an `input` element when it enters the DOM?

#### Scenario

When a button is clicked the input element is displayed. How to set the focus to this element?

#### Code-Snippet

```js
class Component extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showInput: false
    }
  }

  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div onClick={() => {
              this.setState({showInput: true});
              ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.myInput).focus() // <- NOT WORKING
          }}>
            Show Input
          </div>
          {
            (this.state.showInput) ? (
                <input
                    type="text"
                    ref="myInput"
                />
            ) : ""
          }  
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Calling `ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.myInput).focus()` after state change does not work. Also changing just the `style` or `type` property on state change does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` hooks do this:

```
ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.myInput).focus()
```

Comment: Thank you very much this worked! For this case the `componentDidUpdate` did the work! I added the following code: `componentDidUpdate() {
        if (ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.searchInput) !== null) {
            ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.searchInput).focus()
        }
    }`

Comment: One good comment, that was deleted unfortunately, also suggests to use `this.refs.myInput.focus()` instead of `findDOMNode`. Thanks for the that comment though!

Comment: yes dont use ReactDom.findnode thats deprecated ,it skipped my mind
this.refs.myInput.focus()

Comment: or actually you can just use `autoFocus`  inside the input tag

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you only need one visible input on the page at a time to have autofocus  [Poh Zi How's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6150999/poh-zi-how) suggestion of using the `autofocus` is probably the simplest.

`<input type="text" autofocus/>`

should do the trick, no JS needed!

Comment: this is great! Thanks

Comment: In JSX, camelCase attribute: `<input type="text" autoFocus />`

Answer (score 4):

you should use ref

```
<input ref={(input) => { this.inputSearch = input; }} defaultValue="search ... " />
```

and use this code for focus

```
this.inputSearch.focus();
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to define the variable as `HTMLInputElement` 1st...

```
private inputSearch: HTMLInputElement;
```

And then add this into the control:

```
ref={(input) => { this.inputSearch = input; }}
```

THEN I could get this to build/work:

```
this.inputSearch.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

"findDOMNode only works on mounted components (that is, components that have been placed in the DOM). If you try to call this on a component that has not been mounted yet (like calling findDOMNode() in render() on a component that has yet to be created) an exception will be thrown."

As mentioned by Piyush.kapoor, you need to place that in`componentDidMount` and/or `componentDidUpdate`.